# Line entry/count difference between sed and nl on unix vs. mac

Tags: r, macos, unix, sed, newline

I have a simple and annoying problem, and I apologize for not posting an example. The files are big and I haven't been able to recreate the exact issue using smaller files:

These are tab-delimited files (some entries contain `"` `;` or a single space character). On UNIX, when I access a unique word via: `nl file | sed -n '/word/p'` I see that my word is on exactly the same line in all my files.

Now I copy the files to my mac. I run the same command on the same exact files, but the line numbers are all different! The total number of lines via `wc -l` is still identical to the numbers I get in unix, but when I do `nl file | tail -n1` I see a different number. Yet, when I enter the number returned from my unix `nl`, and access the same line via `sed '12345p' file` I get the correct entry!?

My question: I must have something in some of my lines that is interpreted as linebreaks on my mac but not in unix, and only by `nl` not `sed`. Can anyone help me figure out what it is? I already know it's not on every line. I found this issue persists when I load the data into `R`, and I'm stumped. Thank you!

Comment: How did you copy the files? Did the copy translate line endings or are they identical byte for byte on Unix and Mac?

Comment: I copied them using scp. I've never noticed a difference before between a unix file and a mac file.

Comment: Yes, they are identical, byte for byte:

Comment: 17e4759590d804ecb5c44b17982939ae (unix md5sum)

Comment: 17e4759590d804ecb5c44b17982939ae (mac osx md5)

Comment: Right, so the difference is probably in nl itself. Have you considered using a different tool like awk?

Comment: with `awk -F $'\t' '{if ($23 == "word") print FNR "\t" $23}' file` I get the same line number and record as on unix. But my issue is not `nl`, I just used it to troubelshoot. When I load these entries into `R`, I make a dataframe of the exact dimensions (33795 rows x 24 columns), yet the "word" entry is **not** on the same line in all dataframes. So R sees what nl sees. I don't know how to reformat my files to use them, since I can't track the issue :(

Comment: Got it. Have you tried dos2unix to remove any incorrect line breaks? Alternatively, you could search for \n or \r (whichever one shouldn't be there) but you need to do it in binary, not ASCII.

Comment: Last suggestion: you can manually perform a binary search to quickly find the first line where the numbering differs. You know it's between 1 and the line number of "word". Divide that by 2 and check the corresponding line. If the lines don't match (unix vs mac) take the first half, divide by 2 and keep going. If the lines match, take the second half. With a few iterations, you should find the culprit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that (search for \n or \r in binary). I also don't understand it, because i generated these files myself with perl and it gives me exactly what i expect, but only in unix..

Comment: Strangely, when I just grab the column containing the word i look for by `cut -d $'\t' -f23 file` and do `comm -3 file1.txt file2.txt` there's no output - as if the files are exactly identical. So, `nl` and `R` see them in different lines, but when I use the shell extension `$` they're in the same line even in mac!?

Comment: Very odd indeed. Redirect the output of nl on each system to a separate text file and compare them with ``comm -3 nl_unix.txt nl_mac.txt | head -1`` to see where the errors start. (Easier than my binary search suggestion above)

Comment: I think I got it - they start on line 22, in the middle of a long string of comma-separated numbers. Is there a maximum line length parameter that may be different in unix vs. mac??

Comment: I don't think so. Is it possible that your Perl program wrote one of the numbers with a line break? Do the numbers come from some other input that needs to be validated?

Comment: No, the output looks clean. Here's the offending section (in a string of 958 comma-separated integers). In unix, it's an unbroken string after running through `nl`, but the same file on mac `nl` produces white-space characters:

Comment: `2,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24` (unix)

Comment: `2,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24     2 ,24,24,` (mac)

Comment: `R` must be seeing something similar as `nl` and produce a break in the record. Even when I load the object into R on unix and then transfer the .Robjects to my mac R workspace, I reproduce this error. I'm going to have to shorten that list of comma-separated integers I'm afraid

Comment: how they both treat empty or blank line ? (like option -l or --join-blank-lines=), is the same default behavior ? Also, sed have buffer issue, try with a -u (if your version alllow it) to pass in stream version of sed.

Answer (score 1):

"Phantom newlines" can be hidden in text in the form of a multi-byte UTF-8 character called an ["overlong sequence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings).

UTF-8 normally represents ASCII characters as themselves: UTF-8 bytes in the range 0 to 127 are just those character values. However, overlong sequences can be used to (incorrectly) encode ASCII characters using multiple UTF-8 bytes (which are in the range 0x80-0xFF). A properly written UTF-8 decoder must detect overlong sequences and somehow flag them as invalid bytes. A naively written UTF-8 decoder will simply extract the implied character.

Thus, it's possible that your data is being treated as UTF-8, and contains some bytes which look like an overlong sequence for a newline, and that this is fooling some of the software you are working with. A two-byte overlong sequence for a newline would look like `C0 8A`, and a three-byte overlong sequence would be `E0 80 8A`.

It is hard to come up with an alternative hypothesis not involving character encodings.

Comment: Thank you, Kaz - I have to look into that. I ended up rewriting my scripts and didn't run into the same issue though. I'll see whether I can dig out the old files.